# UINavigationController back button triggers the current view to disappear early

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a simple navigation controller in my iPad app, but I'm getting a weird bug that I've never seen before. I can push a view onto the view controller stack fine, but when I hit the back button on the navigation bar, the view disappears before sliding off the screen. I don't do anything funky with viewDidDisappear or anything. Has anyone else run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

If I was having this problem, I'd add log messages to viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, and dealloc. I'm assuming you are using ARC but its not all that critical.

In all cases I would NSLog the method name and the view, like:

NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear: view=%@ animated=%d", self.view, animated);

Make sure you call super in the first two methods.

I suspect your view is getting removed from its superview or released before you think it should be.

Comment: I took a look at this. Everything seems to be behaving as normally. I think it might have something to do with the view controller that pushed the disappearing view controller in the first place, because regardless of which view controller I push onto the stack, this happens.

Comment: The first view controller will get a viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear - make sure problem isn't coming from there. My last company no one thought those messages would happen but once!

Comment: After further examination, none of those things seem to be causing the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, if you can copy your project, then cull it down to just two views with nothing interesting in them that will cause this, you could post that (as a zip) to your public folder on DropBox (or use github), then me and possibly others could take a crack at it. Or, two other thoughts - to determine if problem is in the first viewcontroller or the pushed controller. Create a really simple viewcontroller with just a button in it, when button pushed push the view controller, see if the problem goes away. This would help you determine for sure who is the problem.